# Tmux binding error `returned 127` in cygwin

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, cygwin, clipboard

I want to use a clipboard manager in `tmux`. It is the `CopyQ`, but it does not matter, I guess. In `~/.tmux.conf` I set following binding:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi

bind C-y run 'out=`tmux save-buffer - ` && copyq add "$out"'
```

When I press this shortcut 
<kbd>PREFIX</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> the copying to `CopyQ` fails and the following message arises

```
'out=`tmux save-buffer - ` && copyq add "$out"' returned 127
```

However, If I try to enter these commands manually then they works and text copyies from `tmux` buffer to `copyq` as required

```
$ out=`tmux save-buffer - `
$ copyq add "$out"
```

And I need to say that following command works fine and print a text from `tmux` buffer to screen:

```
bind C-w run 'out=`tmux save-buffer - ` && echo "$out"'
```

How I can make original binding work?

Answer (score 1):

Value 127 is [returned](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-fix-bash-127-error-return-code) by your shell /bin/bash when any given command within your bash script or on bash command line is not found in any of the paths defined by PATH system environment variable.

So, tmux just have not `CopyQ` in its `$PATH` variable, when starts binding. If one add full path for `CopyQ` then it fix problem:

```
bind C-y run 'out=`tmux save-buffer - ` &&  /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/CopyQ/copyq add "$out"'
```

Other approach is to add `source ~/.bashrc` to `~/bash_profile`

Comment: Thanks! I need some help if it's happening on linux. I have a similar problem